# Does upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 require all packages to be upgraded?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.04

While upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 found that a lot of packages were listed under "will be upgraded". I know there's a capability to hold certain package upgrades by doing `apt mark-hold <package>`. **But I'm not sure which packages am I able to hold and still feel safe on being in Ubuntu 20.04!**

For example: `nginx` is upgraded by default. Is it safe to hold it?
Where can I find out whether an old version package is still compatible with Ubuntu 20.04?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @user535733, I'm testing right now to understand what else needs to be upgraded. If I'll need to upgrade all related upgrades better checking now.

Comment: it is best to let the upgrade do its stuff and remove and replace the packages. it is a lot easier to change things in a fully functioning system.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu does not test older (wrong-version) packages with newer releases of Ubuntu.

Advice for LTS users: Wait until the upgrade path from 18.04 to 20.04.1 opens in late July 2020.

If downtime is important to you, consider testing an upgrade using a Virtual Machine. A few minutes to set up a testing environment may be worthwhile for some users.

Selective upgrading means you will be running a Frankensystem of cobbled-together wrong-version packages. That may cause problems that are hard to reproduce or diagnose. We generally advise against mixing packages from different releases of Ubuntu.